# How to host Java application package similar to Python's pypi.org?

Tags: open-source, python, java, software-development, command-line

I have a `Java` application which I would like to host on some sort of free hosting website. Later, users can install that application via a command-line tool and use it easily.

While searching, I found that its possible to do via https://pypi.org/ for Python applications but not sure how to do the same for Java applications.

Does anyone know if there is a way to achieve something similar for Java application?

Comment: The equivalent to that would be https://mvnrepository.com/

Comment: @golimar Thanks a lot for your response but MvnRepository is just to host the dependency right? Later we can add that dependency to our project and use them but I am looking for a way to host and install the application via command line and also use it via command line.